# installation of nuget on a teamcity server

Tags: teamcity, nuget, teamcity-7.0

We have a TeamCity 7 server and we'd like to enable it for nuget.

We don't have any external network connectivity on the box, so when asked to download nuget, TeamCity says

"Failed to fetch latest NuGet from default feed. 
Connection to http://packages.nuget.org refused"

Is there a workaround to install nuget, from a standalone exe or something, in such a way that TeamCity recognizes the installation?

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you manually drop the package:
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5317896#5317896

Others maybe interested in setting up proxy settings:
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5452590#5452590